# Controls align / snap to with distance at runtime

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create a small program , where the user can add Panels at runtime .
Then align them and if the Panels are from a certain distance from each other then "snap" together .

The following code almost works :

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls , Math;

type
  TMain = class(TForm)
    pmOptions: TPopupMenu;
    miAdd: TMenuItem;
    miMove: TMenuItem;
    menRefresh: TMenuItem;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure miAddClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure ControlMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ControlMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ControlMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,Y: Integer);


    type
      TBox = record
        ID : integer;
        Panel : TPanel;
      end;

    var Box : array of TBox;

    inReposition : boolean;
    oldPos : TPoint;
    oldObjectPos : TPoint;

    alignX,alignY : integer;
    isAlignX,isAlignY : boolean;

    moveLeft,moveRight,moveUp,moveDown : boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Counter : integer;
  end;

var
  Main: TMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMain.ControlMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  (Sender as TPanel).Color:=clYellow;

  inReposition:=true;
  SetCapture(TWinControl(Sender).Handle);
  GetCursorPos(oldPos);

  oldObjectPos:=(Sender as TPanel).BoundsRect.CenterPoint;

  isAlignX:=false;
  isAlignY:=false;

  moveLeft:=false;
  moveRight:=false;
  moveUp:=false;
  moveDown:=false;

end;

procedure TMain.ControlMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,Y: Integer);
var
  newPos : TPoint;
  newObjectPos : TPoint;

  Panel : TPanel;
  NearNeighbour : TPanel;
  FarNeighbourX,FarNeighbourY : TPanel;

  i : integer;

  NearOld , NearCurr : double;
  FarXOld , FarXCurr : double;
  FarYOld , FarYCurr : double;


begin
  if inReposition then
  begin

    Panel := Sender as TPanel;

    GetCursorPos(newPos);

    newObjectPos:=Panel.BoundsRect.CenterPoint;

    // mouse cursor direction
    moveLeft := oldObjectPos.X > newObjectPos.X;
    moveRight := oldObjectPos.X < newObjectPos.X;
    moveUp := oldObjectPos.Y > newObjectPos.Y;
    moveDown := oldObjectPos.Y < newObjectPos.Y;

    oldObjectPos:=newObjectPos;

    Screen.Cursor := crSize;

    if isAlignX = false then
      Panel.Left := Panel.Left - oldPos.X + newPos.X;

    if isAlignY = false then
      Panel.Top := Panel.Top - oldPos.Y + newPos.Y;

    NearNeighbour := nil;
    FarNeighbourX := nil;
    FarNeighbourY := nil;

    NearOld := Infinity;
    FarXOld := NegInfinity;
    FarYOld := NegInfinity;

    for i := 0 to ComponentCount-1 do
    begin
      // here we loop until we find neerest component
      if (Components[i] is TPanel) and (Components[i] <> Panel) then
      begin

        // Snap to nearest neighbour
        NearCurr := sqrt(sqr(Panel.BoundsRect.CenterPoint.X-(Components[i] as TPanel).BoundsRect.CenterPoint.X) + sqr(Panel.BoundsRect.CenterPoint.Y-(Components[i] as TPanel).BoundsRect.CenterPoint.Y));

        if NearCurr <= NearOld then
        begin
          NearOld:=NearCurr;
          NearNeighbour:=Components[i] as TPanel;
        end;

        // Check Neighbours on X Axis
        if (Panel.Top) = (Components[i] as TPanel).Top then
        begin
          FarXCurr := ABS(Panel.BoundsRect.CenterPoint.X - (Components[i] as TPanel).BoundsRect.CenterPoint.X);

          if FarXCurr > FarXOld then
          begin
            FarXOld := FarXCurr;
            FarNeighbourX := Components[i] as TPanel;
          end;
        end;

        // Check Neighbours on Y Axix
        if Panel.Left = (Components[i] as TPanel).Left then
        begin
          FarYCurr := ABS(Panel.BoundsRect.CenterPoint.Y - (Components[i] as TPanel).BoundsRect.CenterPoint.Y);

          if FarYCurr > FarYOld then
          begin
            FarYOld := FarYCurr;
            FarNeighbourY := Components[i] as TPanel;
          end;
        end;

      end;
    end;

    if Assigned(NearNeighbour) then
    begin
      Label1.Caption:=NearNeighbour.Caption;
    end;


    if Assigned(FarNeighbourY) then
      if FarNeighbourY.Left = Panel.Left then
      begin
        if isAlignX = false then
        begin
          alignX:=Mouse.CursorPos.X;

          isAlignX := true;

          Panel.Left := FarNeighbourY.Left;
        end;
      end;

    if isAlignX = true then
    begin
      with Canvas do
      begin
        pen.Color := clBlue;
        MoveTo(FarNeighbourY.Left,FarNeighbourY.Top+FarNeighbourY.Height);
        LineTo(Panel.Left,Panel.Top);
      end;

      if ABS(alignX - newPos.X) > 10 then
      begin
        isAlignX:=false;
        Self.Repaint;
      end;

      // only let it go up and down
      if Assigned(NearNeighbour) then
      begin
        if moveUp then
          if ABS(Panel.Top - NearNeighbour.BoundsRect.Bottom) <= 10 then
            Panel.Top := NearNeighbour.BoundsRect.Bottom + 10;

        if moveDown then
          if ABS(Panel.BoundsRect.Bottom - NearNeighbour.Top) <= 10 then
            Panel.Top := NearNeighbour.Top - Panel.Height - 10;
      end;

    end
    else
    begin
      oldPos.X := newPos.X;
    end;

    if Assigned(FarNeighbourX) then
      if FarNeighbourX.Top = Panel.Top then
      begin
        if isAlignY = false then
        begin
          alignY:=Mouse.CursorPos.Y;

          isAlignY := true;

          Panel.Top := FarNeighbourX.Top;
        end;
      end;


    if isAlignY = true then
    begin
      with Canvas do
      begin
        pen.Color := clBlue;
        MoveTo(FarNeighbourX.Left+FarNeighbourX.Width,FarNeighbourX.Top);
        LineTo(Panel.Left,Panel.Top);
      end;

      if ABS(alignY - newPos.Y) > 10 then
      begin
        isAlignY:=false;
        Self.Repaint;
      end;

      // only let it go right and left
      if Assigned(NearNeighbour) then
      begin
        if moveLeft then
          if ABS(Panel.Left - NearNeighbour.BoundsRect.Right) <= 10 then
            Panel.Left := NearNeighbour.BoundsRect.Right+10;

        if moveRight then
          if ABS(Panel.BoundsRect.Right - NearNeighbour.Left) <= 10 then
            Panel.Left := NearNeighbour.Left-Panel.Width-10;
      end;

    end
    else
    begin
      oldPos.Y := newPos.Y;
    end;

  end;
end;

procedure TMain.ControlMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  (Sender as TPanel).Color:=clWhite;

  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  ReleaseCapture;
  inReposition:=false;

  Self.Repaint;

  isAlignX:=false;
  isAlignY:=false;

  moveLeft:=false;
  moveRight:=false;
  moveUp:=false;
  moveDown:=false;
end;

procedure TMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Counter := 0;
end;

procedure TMain.miAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inc(Counter);

  SetLength(Box,length(Box)+1);
  Box[High(Box)].ID:=Counter;
  Box[High(Box)].Panel:=TPanel.Create(Self);
  Box[High(Box)].Panel.Parent:=Self;

  Box[High(Box)].Panel.Left:=CalcCursorPos.X;
  Box[High(Box)].Panel.Top:=CalcCursorPos.Y;

  Box[High(Box)].Panel.Width:=100;
  Box[High(Box)].Panel.Height:=100;

  Box[High(Box)].Panel.Color:=clWhite;
  Box[High(Box)].Panel.ParentBackground:=false;

  Box[High(Box)].Panel.Caption:=Box[High(Box)].ID.ToString;

  Box[High(Box)].Panel.BevelInner:=bvNone;
  Box[High(Box)].Panel.BevelKind:=bkFlat;
  Box[High(Box)].Panel.BevelOuter:=bvNone;

  Box[High(Box)].Panel.OnMouseDown:=ControlMouseDown;
  Box[High(Box)].Panel.OnMouseUp:=ControlMouseUp;
  Box[High(Box)].Panel.OnMouseMove:=ControlMouseMove;
end;

end.
```

I have a problem with the **NearNeighbour** , the instant these lines are uncommented :

```
  if Assigned(NearNeighbour) then
  begin
    if moveLeft then
      if ABS(Panel.Left - NearNeighbour.BoundsRect.Right) <= 10 then
        Panel.Left := NearNeighbour.BoundsRect.Right+10;

    if moveRight then
      if ABS(Panel.BoundsRect.Right - NearNeighbour.Left) <= 10 then
        Panel.Left := NearNeighbour.Left-Panel.Width-10;
  end;
```

Sometimes my Application dies with Access Violation . Can someone please help me fix this ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**

I have found the place where the Access Violation happens , and I am pretty sure the problem is related to the Snap , because it "vibrates" instead of snapping in cleanly .

```
MoveTo(FarNeighbourX.Left+FarNeighbourX.Width,FarNeighbourX.Top);
LineTo(Panel.Left,Panel.Top);
```

and

```
MoveTo(FarNeighbourY.Left,FarNeighbourY.Top+FarNeighbourY.Height);
LineTo(Panel.Left,Panel.Top);
```

Sometimes the FarNeighbourX and FarNeighbourY is nil . I "fixed" it by doing a try except here . But it would be better to solve it by making the Snapto object not "vibrate" +/- 1 Pixel

**UPDATE 2**

not sure if this is the best solution, but I kinda solved it by adding **inReposition:=false** whenever they snap together .

```
if ABS(Panel.Left - NearNeighbour.BoundsRect.Right) <= 10 then
begin
  Panel.Left := NearNeighbour.BoundsRect.Right+10;
  inReposition:=false;
end;
```

Comment: On which line does Access Violation occurs? At first look your code seems OK. Any way I think you could greatly simplify your code by using some of the TRectangle helper methods. For instance you could enlarge BoundRect of the panel you are dragging by using [Inflate](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Types.TRect.Inflate) for snapping distance and then perform intersection test of this enlarged Rectangle with rectangles of other components using [IntersectsWith](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Types.TRect.IntersectsWith) ...

Comment: ..  Since you have inflated original BoundsRect `IntersectsWith` will return true whenever your two components are close enough to snap. Then you could also make use of [Intersect](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Types.TRect.Intersect) procedure that returns Rectangle that represents the area where your two rectangles intercepts each other. You can then use this information to determine for how much and into which direction you need to move your component to perform a desired snap.

Comment: @SilverWarior : the problem is caused by the if Assigned(NearNeighbour) part ... if I leave those uncommented sooner or later the software dies. I am having problems figuring out why, because it does not always happen . It might be that the current snap is working incorrectly. When I drag the Panel it goes bellow <= 10 for a second then back to 10 . So it might be that this is causing the problem .

Comment: @SilverWarior : it should simply stop at the distance 10 instead of going in 9 then back to 10 ....

Comment: The reason why distance can get below 10 is because by default when you are moving your mouse around the mouse cursor is not always moving pixel by pixel but might jump for few pixels at a time in specific direction. Faster you move the mouse more pixels it might jump over. This is actually called mouse acceleration. So you should check to see if the distance would be below desired value before you move the panel to new position.

Comment: Wait I'm now confused. Why you don't want the distance to become less than 10? I thought you are trying to achieve so that when to controls move close enough to each other they snap to each other so you don't have to move them right to each other manually.  Not wanting distance between them to be less than 10 pixels would mean that you always wants to keep some space between them like some kind of boundary. So which is it?

Comment: @SilverWarior : sorry . They should "snap" together with a boundary of 10 ( right now )

Comment: You should have included this information in your question. So what is the snapping distance then.

Comment: @SilverWarior : right now 10 as seen above in the code.